# How to have multiples matches for a snippet in Vim's snipMate plugin (with a dropdown menu)

Tags: vim, plugins, code-snippets

snipmates expands div as `<div id = " ">` . I want snipmate to show a dropdown menu where I can choose between `div id ="" and div class=""` (after creating the second one).

The documentation says:

```
snippet trigger A description of snippet #1
    expand this text
snippet trigger A description of snippet #2
    expand THIS text!
```

but this effectively opens a small window below where I choose a number and then press enter. But is there a way to make it a dropdown menu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't a way to make the current implementation use a popup menu like is used for completion.  You could file a feature request against snipMate and see if the author can change it to do that, but I'm not sure that'd be easy to do.

Answer (score 3):

I like to use:

```
<div ${1:id}="${2}">
</div>
```

This allows me to replace *id* with *class* when needed, then tab to the value placeholder.

Answer (score 1):

This doesnt answer your question directly, but if you dont get a definite answer from others consider making two keys words for the two snippets. Something like ..

`divi` --> `<div id=""`

`divc` --> `<div class=""`